Computable Bijection between natural numbers and rooted trees
I am searching for a one-to-one mapping (bijection) between the set of natural numbers  and the set of rooted, unordered trees. I need a pair of functions (:→, :→) where  is the set of all rooted, unordered trees, such that each tree in
 corresponds uniquely to exactly one natural number. This is sometimes also referred to as "ranking and unranking", sometimes simply as "generating trees".
While I found numerous algorithms for solving this problem in theory (e.g., Beyer, Sawada), most of these define a bijection via a successor function. As a result, computing the -th tree involves generating all −1 predecessors. This is intractable for large .
Other bijections I have found, e.g., the work of Cappello, rely on prime factorization. They are mathematically elegant, but again computationally impractical for very large numbers. What I am currently using is the one by Y.Abe, which works well in practice until 2^30.
As an example, Abe's bijection is obtained by recursively decomposing the input number into an array of its prime factors, and then reducing each prime to its rank (i.e., th prime number has rank ). Computing the factorisation and the prime rank means that a normal computer can't go past ~2^30 (on my M1).
I'd like, ideally, to reach scales like 2^1000. I wonder if this is even possible for unordered trees. I could compromise on generating binary trees only, but I could not find anything.
An illustration from Abe's work, showing the enumeration
